# how to store remote biometric (essl) logs to remote mysql database?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, biometrics, time-and-attendance

i'm working with bio-metric(essl) to store the logs directly to mysql database.
i have 20 bio-metric machines in different locations and want to store the logs of 20 machines to a centralized mysql database. PHP

Comment: Please add your sample codes. and give us detail about your database structure

Comment: even iam asking for how to connect biometric machine  essl to mysql centerlised database

Comment: You may need to communicate your devices through http. Refer  http://essl.co.in/application/zk-teco-essl-api-integration.html , if helps you